# How can I alter a Chocolatey package's $url for install

Tags: powershell, proxy, http-proxy, chocolatey

TLDR version: I need to be able to append to the end of the URL that a chocolatey package specifies for its download source.

I'm trying to use Chocolatey to install the Android-SDK package and am having an issue with my filtering proxy (the functionality and provision of which, I have no control over). The proxy is detected properly but it will block URLs that contain certain patterns and issue a 403 return (in this case it's because the URL is to a `.exe`). So running `choco install -y android-sdk` causes the following error.

```
2015-03-12 15:14:47,639 [INFO ] - ============================================================
2015-03-12 15:14:47,664 [INFO ] - Chocolatey v0.9.9.2
2015-03-12 15:14:47,730 [INFO ] - Installing the following packages:
2015-03-12 15:14:47,753 [INFO ] - android-sdk
2015-03-12 15:14:47,754 [INFO ] - By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
2015-03-12 15:14:49,221 [INFO ] - 
android-sdk v24.0.2
2015-03-12 15:14:50,525 [INFO ] -  Using this proxyserver: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
2015-03-12 15:14:52,175 [INFO ] -  Attempt to get headers for http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.0.2-windows.exe failed.
2015-03-12 15:14:52,175 [INFO ] -    Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
2015-03-12 15:14:52,180 [INFO ] -  Downloading android-sdk 32 bit
2015-03-12 15:14:52,180 [INFO ] -    from 'http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.0.2-windows.exe'
2015-03-12 15:14:52,213 [INFO ] -  Using this proxyserver: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
2015-03-12 15:14:52,329 [ERROR] -  Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
2015-03-12 15:14:52,330 [ERROR] -  At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Get-WebFile.ps1:66 char:3
2015-03-12 15:14:52,330 [ERROR] -  +   $res = $req.GetResponse();
2015-03-12 15:14:52,330 [ERROR] -  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2015-03-12 15:14:52,331 [ERROR] -      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
2015-03-12 15:14:52,331 [ERROR] -      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
2015-03-12 15:14:52,354 [ERROR] -  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
2015-03-12 15:14:52,354 [ERROR] -  At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Get-WebFile.ps1:138 char:3
2015-03-12 15:14:52,355 [ERROR] -  +   $res.Close();
2015-03-12 15:14:52,356 [ERROR] -  +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
2015-03-12 15:14:52,356 [ERROR] -      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
2015-03-12 15:14:52,357 [ERROR] -      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
2015-03-12 15:14:54,374 [ERROR] -  Chocolatey expected a file to be downloaded to 
2015-03-12 15:14:54,375 [ERROR] -  'X:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\android-sdk\android-sdkInstall.exe' but nothing exists at that 
2015-03-12 15:14:54,375 [ERROR] -  location.
2015-03-12 15:14:54,376 [ERROR] -  At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Get-ChocolateyWebFile.ps1:148 char:24
2015-03-12 15:14:54,376 [ERROR] -  +   if (!($fi.Exists)) {{ throw "Chocolatey expected a file to be downloaded to `'$ ...
2015-03-12 15:14:54,377 [ERROR] -  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2015-03-12 15:14:54,377 [ERROR] -      + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Chocolatey expe... that location.:String) [], RuntimeException
2015-03-12 15:14:54,378 [ERROR] -      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Chocolatey expected a file to be downloaded to 'X:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cho 
2015-03-12 15:14:54,378 [ERROR] -     colatey\android-sdk\android-sdkInstall.exe' but nothing exists at that location.
2015-03-12 15:14:54,618 [ERROR] - android-sdk install not successful.
2015-03-12 15:14:54,621 [ERROR] - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\android-sdk\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2015-03-12 15:14:56,643 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 package(s). 1 package(s) failed.
 See the log for details.
2015-03-12 15:14:56,643 [ERROR] - Failures:
2015-03-12 15:14:56,645 [ERROR] -  - android-sdk
```

I could create my own package with the `chocolateyInstall.ps1` and `chocolateyUninstall.ps1` listed on the package's web page and alter the URL, but that negates any benefit of using a package manager to simplify the process of managing programs and dependencies.

So I am wondering if there is some way that I can simply append a string that allows the URL through the proxy regardless of the file extension (to be clear, I know what this string is, I just don't know how to append it to the URL specified by the package).

Comment: Are you able to download the android sdk directly from the site? It is the same link that chocolatey is using to download the installer.

Comment: @mikez I can't using the link that is in the chocolatey package, but I can modify it slightly to allow it through the proxy by adding a query string on the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer and I'm not sure how *safe* this answer is (in terms of surviving updates to Chocolatey itself), but it's resolved my immediate issue with the android-sdk package. Unfortunately, any package that implements its own download code bypasses this "fix".

I noticed the line in the error log that highlights one of the failure points as `2015-03-12 15:14:52,330 [ERROR] -  At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Get-WebFile.ps1:66 char:3` and wondered if I could alter the URL in that powershell script. After a bit of trial and error with the exact escaping that was needed for the appended string I managed to get it downloading the file, but the header check was still failing.

I then checked the other files in the `helpers/functions/` directory and found `Get-ChocolateyWebFile.ps1` which is what appears to call `Get-WebFile.ps1` and also does the header check to see if it needs SSL.

So, I created a new powershell function file to perform the necessary URL rewrites in a function named `Get-ProxyUrl` and added this line to `Get-ChocolateyWebFile.ps1` after the section that checks for 32bit/64bit URL but before the header check on the URL (line 101 in my version 0.9.9.2 file).

```
$url = Get-ProxyUrl($url)
```

I then also added it to the very beginning of the `Get-WebFile` function definition in `Get-WebFile.ps1` to capture any direct calls to that function.

So, this will allow me to fix any packages that use `Install-ChocolateyPackage`, `Get-ChocolateyWebFile` or `Get-WebFile`, but still leaves some packages - such as JDK8 - that specify their own file download code and still fail.

So, a better solution would capture any URLs from a Chocolatey install... probably the only way to do this would be to install a local proxy server that chocolatey can use that would transform the URL before being passed on

Comment: Perhaps a more robust way to do this would be using a proxy function. That would allow you to inspect/modify the arguments of `Get-WebFile`. However, I don't think there is way to intercept all calls to `WebRequest.Create`.

Comment: @mikez yes, perhaps I could set up a local proxy for all chocolatey traffic that then forwards it on